# Delete the log files have 30 days old timestamp in log filename in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a below log files who have date mention in filename. I want to delete the files have 30 days old date in filename. someone please provide the solution.

log files:-

```
fortinetPerformanceMet_01_11_2022.log
fortinetTokenGeneration_05_11_2022.log
fortinetTopDestination_10_12_2022.log
fortinetTopSource_11_12_2022.log
```

I  want to delete a logfiles who have 30 days old date in filename.
after deleting 30 days old files the expected output from above file will be

```
fortinetTopDestination_10_12_2022.log
fortinetTopSource_11_12_2022.log
```

I tried below

`find /path/to/files/ -type f  -name "*_*_*_$2022.log" -mtime +30 -delete`, but it will delete the files according to the file timestamp.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for `rsyslog` than for manual bash processing.

Comment: Show the output of `ls -al` for the above files. You are requiring the `"*2022.log"` match AND `-mtime` greater than 30 24-hour periods ago. If the files are actually of a more recent date on disk, the command will always fail.

Comment: What do you think `"...$2022.log"` will become?

Comment: When creating the files, omit `_12_2022` in the file names and the problem will no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Your `date` command supports `-d` option.
- The timestamp in the filenames represents `dd_mm_yyyy`.

Then would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldday=$(LC_TIME=C date -d "-30 days" "+%Y_%m_%d")
while IFS= read -r f; do
    if [[ $f =~ _([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{4})\.log ]]; then
        timestamp="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        if [[ $oldday > $timestamp ]]; then
            echo rm -- "$f"
        fi
    fi
done < <(find /path/to/files/ -type f -name "*_*_*_*.log")
```

- `oldday` is assigned to the date 30 days ago in the format `yyyy_mm_dd`.
- `timestamp` is re-arranged as `yyyy_mm_dd`.
- Now we can compare them with the `>` operator.

If the output looks good, drop `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the timestamp is given in the filename only.

- We can use regex to extract the `dd_mm_yyyy` components from the filename
- We can rearrange this to `yyyymmdd` format
- Then we can use `yyyymmdd` to convert that to a second relative to an epoch date in seconds using `date +%s`
- We can also get today's date relative to the same epoch date in seconds using `date +%s`
- Then we can simply subtract the two dates and change the units from seconds to days
- If the days is less than 30 we don't delete

Here's the code:

```bash
now=$(date +%s)
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*_*_*.log")
do
    if [[ $f =~ _([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{4})\.log ]]; then
        yyyymmdd=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        old=$(date +%s -d $yyyymmdd)
        ((age = (now -old) / 60 / 60 / 24))
        echo "file: $f age: $age"
        if (( age < 30 )); then continue; fi
        echo delete $f
        # rm $f # UNCOMMENT WHEN YOU'RE HAPPY
    fi
done
```

For your sample data, the above script outputs:

```bash
file: ./fortinetPerformanceMet_01_11_2022.log age: 41
delete ./fortinetPerformanceMet_01_11_2022.log
file: ./fortinetTopDestination_10_12_2022.log age: 2
file: ./fortinetTopSource_11_12_2022.log age: 1
file: ./fortinetTokenGeneration_05_11_2022.log age: 37
delete ./fortinetTokenGeneration_05_11_2022.log
```

Comment: That's a lot of calls to perl and date. `find /path/to/files/ -type f  -name '*_*_*_2022.log' -execdir perl -le '$max=shift; for(@ARGV){ print "unlink $_" if /_(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\d{4})\.log$/ && "$3$2$1" < $max }' -- $(date -d 'today - 29 days' +%Y%m%d) \{} \+`

Comment: Removed `perl` but `date` is still there. You are correct it's being done for every matching file. It is hoped that the parent `find` command does a significant shortlist. You're welcome to post your own answer involving `perl`.